# OptimisticConcurrencyException thrown for a simple fetch/update method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, visual-web-developer-2010

**Environment** 
Entity Framework 4;  Visual Web Developer Express 2010; Database first; SQL Server Express

**Question**

I want to fetch a row from the database, update one field and save back to the database.
Why does the following method throw an `OptimisticConcurrencyException`?

```cs
public static void SetReturnVisit(int firstAppointmentSlotID, int returnAppointmentSlotID) {
    AppointmentSlot slot = m_db.AppointmentSlots.SingleOrDefault(m => m.AppointmentSlotID == firstAppointmentSlotID);
    slot.ReturnAppointmentSlotID = returnAppointmentSlotID;
    m_db.SaveChanges();       
}
```

`m_db` is my `ObjectContext` Entities class.
`AppointmentSlot` database table contains a `Timestamp` field named `Concurrency`.
`Concurrency` property on entity configured as below:

- `StoreGeneratedPattern`: `Computed`
- `Concurrency Mode`: `Fixed`

I am working as a single developer, so nothing else is modifying the record.

I have tried various approaches, like detaching the item, updating field and attaching again.

```cs
public static void SetReturnVisit(int firstAppointmentSlotID, int returnAppointmentSlotID) {
    AppointmentSlot slot = m_db.AppointmentSlots.SingleOrDefault(m => m.AppointmentSlotID == firstAppointmentSlotID);
    m_db.AppointmentSlots.Detach(slot);
    slot.ReturnAppointmentSlotID = returnAppointmentSlotID;
    m_db.AppointmentSlots.Attach(slot);
    m_db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(slot, EntityState.Modified);
    m_db.SaveChanges();       
}
```

Same problem, exception thrown, and it doesn't make sense to do that anyway.

I have checked the value of the `Concurrency` field just before saving and it is the same as that in the database.

I have even toyed with saving the `Concurrency` value, converting it to a Base 64 string, then converting back to a byte array

```cs
string c = Convert.ToBase64String(slot.Concurrency);
slot.Concurrency = Convert.FromBase64String(c);
```

Am I missing something?  Is there another call I should be making?

Apart from this behaviour, the optimistic concurrency is working as expected when fetching from the database and viewing the item detached, then saving.

Note that I am not including my `Try/Catch` code.

**Update**

The following works as expected:

```cs
m_db.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE AppointmentSlot SET ReturnAppointmentSlotID = {0} WHERE AppointmentSlotID = {1} AND Concurrency = {2}", returnAppointmentSlotID, firstAppointmentSlotID, slot.Concurrency);
```

**Update 20131206**

Confusingly I've added another method that uses the same approach (fetch - update some fields - save back) which does not cause the exception, so the problem must lie higher up.  Perhaps some reference are being held.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference I've figured it out.  I'm using the one context per request approach.  It would appear that there must be a reference being held somewhere in the context.  If I change my code to the following then it works as expected.

```
using(AppEntities ae = new AppEntities()){
    var slot = ae.AppointmentSlots.Single(m => m.AppointmentSlotID == firstAppointmentSlotID);
    slot.ReturnAppointmentSlotID = returnAppointmentSlotID;
    ae.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(slot, EntityState.Modified);
    ae.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem probably lies in the fact that I'm performing actions on related entities.  (An appointment has a patient which has appointments each of which have a patient etc circular reference)